# Select2: load data from remote server - add extra data to returned results

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 ajax functionality to load data from remote server.

Everything works fine but now I would like to keep an extra data received by the remote server
and display it when the user selects an option.

is it possible to store extra data and show it when the user makes a selection?

10x

Answer (score 0):

The server should return an array of objects in response to the ajax request. In addition to the "id" and "text" properties, those objects may contain other properties.

You can use the `formatSelection` option to customize the text that is shown when an item is selected.

```
formatSelection: function(item) {
    return item.text + ' ' + item.xxx; // Some other property
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4afb7c6g/4/)